# Is this usage of for .. in acceptable?

Tags: javascript

I'd like to do the same thing using several strings. I'd like to do it like this:

```
names = ["NOTE", "REPLICA", "HINT", "VIEW"];
for (name in names) {
    name = names[name];
    //do stuff
}
```

Then I read [this](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/11/myths-and-realities-of-forin.html). Is it still OK?

Comment: If it works as expected in all environments you want to use it in, then it's OK.

Comment: The key is here: _"`for..in` loops through the enumerable property names of an object, not the indexes of an array"_. So a `for` loop is better. Using `for..in` to loop arrays is not considered good practice.

Comment: I'm going to pass module along to work in environments unknown.

Comment: Find detailed answer here, http://stackoverflow.com/a/3010848/163585

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to go through an array using a number:

```
var i = 0;
for(i=0;i<names.length;i++){
 ...
}
```

the article you link to already mentioned that any other object properties including stuff on Array.prototype or Object.prototype will show up in `for ... in` another reason not to use it is that for .. in for Array's is slower.

That article does mention an edge case where `for ... in` could be faster when the lenght of the array is big but only a couple of items are set. In that case I guess you can use `for ... in` with `hasOwnProperty` and checking if the property is a number:

```
var stuff, index;
stuff = [];
stuff[0] = "zero";
stuff[9999] = "nine thousand nine hundred and ninety-nine";
stuff.name = "foo";
for (index in stuff)
{
    if (stuff.hasOwnProperty(index) && String(Number(index)) === index) {
        console.log("stuff[" + index + "] = " + stuff[index]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a lot slower than just using a `for loop`.

Around `86% slower` in my browser (Google Chrome 28.0.1500.72).

Check out this [benchmark](http://jsperf.com/for-in-vs-regular-for) I made.
While `for..in` loops only ran at `110,772 ops/sec` (still fast), `for` loops ran at `791,792 ops/sec`

I typically use `for..in` loops with `objects`. I believe that's what they are actually for.

Comment: Operations per second is not the metric you should be looking at. A *for* loop will iterate once for each integer from 0 to *length*, a *for..in* loop will only iterate once for each enumerable property, which is potentially thousands fewer operations.